# How do I validate a model based on the attributes of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, model

In Rails4, I have a model that belongs to another model.  How do I validate based on the value of an attribute in the parent model?

In a food menu system, there are categories and dishes that belong to categories.  Some categories have multiple sizes.  If there are multiple sizes, then there must be names for the large and small size; these will be used as labels in views. This can be validated with `presence: true, if: :multi_size?`

Now, if a dish belongs to a category that is multi-sized, then I want to validate that there is a price for both sizes. The large size price is used if the dish is in a single size category, so it must always be present. However, the small size price is only required if the category is mutli sized.

I tried making a method to see if the category is multi sized, but I get this error in irb: `NoMethodError: private method 'multi_size_category' called for #<Dish:0x007ffebd2827b0>`

In rspec I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'multi_size' for nil:NilClass`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string
#  description     :string
#  multi_size      :boolean
#  small_size_name :string
#  large_size_name :string

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dishes

  validates :name,               presence: true
  validates :small_size_name,    presence: true, if: :multi_size?
  validates :large_size_name,    presence: true, if: :multi_size?
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: dishes
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  name             :string
#  category_id      :integer
#  description      :string
#  small_size_price :decimal(, )
#  large_size_price :decimal(, )

class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, required: true

  validates :name,               presence: true
  validates :category_id,        presence: true
  validates :small_size_price,   presence: true, if: :multi_size_category?
  validates :large_size_price,   presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :large_size_price

  private

  def multi_size_category?
    self.category.multi_size
  end

end
```

Here is the factory for dish:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dish do
    name Faker::Food.dish
    association :category, factory: :category
    description Faker::Lorem.sentence
    small_size_price Faker::Number.decimal(2)
    large_size_price Faker::Number.decimal(2)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll refer to @EJ2015's answer which is better and points out that the underlying issue is poor modeling.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you tried to call `dish.multi_size_category?` directly in console, which caused your first problem (it's a private method). And the second error happened because you didn't set up the category for the dish in your factory (thus `self.category` is nil). You might want to make sure your test objects are valid first.

Personally, I feel your data structure is too rigid and there are dependencies that should be removed. For example, Category shouldn't know anything about dish size (i.e. single responsibility).

It might be better to have four classes: Category, Dish, Size and DishSize, where category has_many dishes. and dishes has a many_to_many with sizes through a dish_sizes table, where you can specify the name and price for each dish/size combo. This way you're free to create new sizes (medium maybe?), and you only need to validate DishSize to have price and name present.

Comment: ok, I concede the private method, but in my factory I do set up the category.  See updated post above.

Comment: I agree your later method would make it more extensible, but all dishes have only one or two prices in this restaurant, and this has been static for years (this is a website re-design).  For example in the category "Soup" there is a small size "cup", and a large size "bowl".  With my way I only have to define the size name once per category.  With your method I need to rename the size for each dish, and then what do I do if two dishes in the same category have different size names?

Comment: I tried @max suggestion of   delegate :multi_size?, to: :category  but I got this error: Dish Model should validate that :name cannot be empty/falsy
     Failure/Error: delegate :multi_size?, to: :category

     Module::DelegationError:
       Dish#multi_size? delegated to category.multi_size?, but category is nil:

Comment: spec/models/dish_spec.rb https://gist.github.com/5504c9ed41369378bd96b410b9f86a43

Comment: full dish factory: https://gist.github.com/facb054af2d523dc785b5c394bef3111

Comment: You should only call your `#multi_size_category?` if category exists. Then your validations will work properly.  But am not sure why your first failed example didn't create a category. Maybe you can try manually create a category and see what is the error there.

Comment: I wound up using `delegate :multi_size?, to: :category`   with   `validates :small_size_price,   presence: true, if: :multi_size?`   I had to use a before block to create a category in my spec and everything worked ok.